# Write on image using PIL/PILLOW

Tags: python, python-imaging-library

Good night.

Today I`m trying to learn PIL/Pillow in Python.

I used the following code:

```
import PIL
import PIL.Image as Image
import PIL.ImageDraw as ImageDraw
import PIL.ImageFont as ImageFont

font = ImageFont.truetype("C:\Windows\Fonts\Verdanab.ttf", 80)

img = Image.open("C:/Users/imagem/fundo_preto.png")
draw = ImageDraw.Draw(img)


filename = "info.txt"
for line in open(filename):
    print line
    x = 0
    y = 0
    draw.text((x, y),line,(255,255,255),font=font)
    img.save("a_test.png")
    x += 10
    y += 10
```

I don`t know the "draw.text()" function works but i tried to writte the following on a black background image i have.

```
Line 1
Line 2
Line 3
Line 4
Line 5
```

All i get is these lines one over the other on the same line.

How does this function work and how do i get the position of lines in different place instead of one over the other.

Comment: The initialization of `x` and `y` should be moved before the loop, otherwise `x += 10; y += 10` would not have any effect. Also I would save the image after the loop. The font path can be given as raw string `r"C:\Windows\Fonts\Verdana.ttf"` to prevent the special meaning of the backslash in strings.

Comment: Since we are talking about fonts. Were do i get a font that emulates a terminal font?  I am trying to emulate a screen of a command prompt terminal but the font i am using is not that great for that.

Comment: Maybe, you want to use a mono-spaced font. BTW, a more portable way for the fonts directory of Windows: `os.path.join(os.environ['WINDIR'], 'Fonts')`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're resetting `x=0`, `y=0` each time through the loop: that's why it's overprinting itself. Other than that, you have the right idea.

Move those lines outside your loop so they only get set once at the beginning.

```
x = 0
y = 0

for line in open(filename):
    print line
    draw.text((x, y),line,(255,255,255),font=font)
    img.save("a_test.png")
    x += 10
    y += 10
```

Comment: Btw, I am trying to use the Terminal windows font but apparently PIL does not support it. How do i use the terminal font?

Comment: The image should be saved *after* the loop once.

Answer (score 2):

Extensions to pbuck's [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/43565932/6235094), that moves the initialization of `x` and `y` outside of the loop.

- It is not efficient to save the image in the loop body. This should be moved after the loop.
- The font path should use the raw string format to prevent the special meaning of the backslash. Alternatively, the backslash can be doubled, or the forward slash can be used.
- Terminal fonts are usually mono-spaced, which `Verdana` is not. The example below uses the font `Consolas`.
- The font size is 80, thus the vertical increment should be larger than 10 to prevent overprinting.

Example file:

```
import os
import PIL.Image as Image
import PIL.ImageDraw as ImageDraw
import PIL.ImageFont as ImageFont

fonts_dir = os.path.join(os.environ['WINDIR'], 'Fonts')
font_name = 'consolab.ttf'
font = ImageFont.truetype(os.path.join(fonts_dir, font_name), 80)

img = Image.new("RGB", (400, 350), "black")
draw = ImageDraw.Draw(img)

filename = "info.txt"
x = y = 0
for line in open(filename):
    print(line)
    draw.text((x, y), line, (255, 255, 255), font=font)
    x += 20
    y += 80

img.save("a_test.png")
```

[image: Result]